# How to get all YouTube iframe from HTML using regex

Tags: php, regex, youtube, wordpress, preg-match-all

I want to get all YouTube `iframe` using regex and want to add specific tag to each record found.

For example `<youtube-frame></youtube-frame>` to iframe begeing and end.

**Needed output:**

```
<youtube-frame><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vakfMRyjulw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></youtube-frame>

<youtube-frame><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aDGWMlKPKDs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></youtube-frame>
```

**My Code**

```
$embed = '
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vakfMRyjulw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe width="600" height="350" src="https://tune.pk/player/embed_player.php?vid=6508414&folderp2016/05/04/&width=600&height=350&autoplay=no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen scrolling="no"></iframe>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aDGWMlKPKDs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe width="600" height="350" src="https://tune.pk/player/embed_player.php?vid=6508414&folder=2016/05/04/&width=600&height=350&autoplay=no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen scrolling="no"></iframe>

<iframe width="600" height="350" src="https://tune.pk/player/embed_player.php?vid=6508414&folder=2016/05/04/&width=600&height=350&autoplay=no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen scrolling="no"></iframe>
';
```

**What I have tried?**

```
$pattern = '/<iframe\.*src=\"//youtube"\.*/';
$iframeSrc = preg_match($pattern, $embed, $matches);
var_dump($iframeSrc);
```

Comment: Error_reporting is not an option for you? Why do you think `src=\"//youtube"` would match `src="https://www.youtube.…` ?

Comment: I already answered, but still: What would be missing at your question below "What I have tried?" is the result of the code you tried (such as the output of `var_dump`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$iframeSrc = preg_replace('/<iframe[^>]*src\s*=\s*"?https?:\/\/[^\s"\/]*youtube.com(?:\/[^\s"]*)?"?[^>]*>.*?<\/iframe>/i', '<youtube-frame>$0</youtube-frame>', $embed);
```

This uses `preg_replace` and a global regex to replace all YouTube IFrame tags (including their closing tags) with `<youtube-frame>$0</youtube-frame>` where `$0` is the original string.

The regex could theoretically be simplified if you are totally sure about the format of your input, but I designed it to be robust enough to cope with other syntaxes such as `src=http://example.com` or `src = "http://example.com"` etc. which are accepted by browsers nowadays, and it only matches sources on `*.youtube.com` domains and not something like `myyoutubesite.com`.

Comment: Thank you @CherryDT Could you please explain what `gi`do here `<\/iframe>/gi`

Comment: `g` makes it global so it matches multiple times (otherwise it would match only one time plus any submatches), `i` makes it case-insensitive because `<IFRAME>` is also a valid way to define an IFrame, as would be `<iFrAmE>`.